# How far away can a tidally locked planet be from a star?

Tags: astronomy, tidally-locked

I have a planet in my worldbuilding project that, fifth planet from its small (compared to the Sun) star, which is meant to be tidally locked. Could a planet as far away that be tidally locked?

Comment: Fifth planet out doesn’t tell us very much. What’s the distance in kilometres or AU, and what’s the mass of the star?

Comment: The farther away from the star, the less and less likely it is for a planet to be tidally locked. In our Solar System, the only planet which is locked into a spin-orbit resonance is tiny Mercury orbiting so close to the big Sun. (A tidal lock is the particular case of a 1:1 spin-orbit resonance. Mercury's spin-orbit resonance is 3:2, 3 rotations for each 2 orbital periods.)

Comment: [Here is a source](https://eos.org/features/tidally-locked-and-loaded-with-questions) which may assist in your understanding. There are a lot more factors than even the other comments suggest, such as makeup of the world in question, does it have a moon, what kind of star does it orbit, plus I'm sure there's many more.

Comment: All planets eventually will be tidally locked. It just takes a really long time. So the question is how old is your star system? Being 5th or 6th is no issue.

Answer (score 2):

## Your header and body ask two different questions.

### To answer the header: As far as you want, provided your system is old enough for tidal locking to have occurred. (This may be a *very* long time, possibly older than the universe itself.)

Orbital systems trend toward stability over time. *How much* time varies quite a bit, and there is some math we can do to try and approximate a good number.

[This article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103596901177?via%3Dihub) gives the basic equation and standard assumptions for determining the necessary time for a tidal lock to occur.

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx {\frac {\omega a^{6}IQ}{3Gm_{p}^{2}k_{2}R^{5}}}}$$

Making a whole bunch of simplifying assumptions (the [Tidal Locking Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) has a handy breakdown of this process), we can reduce that to:

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 6\ {\frac {a^{6}R\mu }{m_{s}m_{p}^{2}}}\times 10^{10}\ {\text{yr}}}$$

In this form of the equation, our remaining unknowns are:

- **a** - the semi-major axis (essentially the size of the orbit)
- **R** - the mean radius of your planet/satellite
- **μ** - the rigidity of the orbiting body (usually about 3×10^10 N·m^−2 for rocky planets)
- **m_s** - the mass of the star
- **m_p** - the mass of the planet

As you can probably tell, the governing variable here is the semi-major axis, being raised to the 6th power.

To illustrate this point, here is the result for Earth in its current orbit:

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 6\ {\frac {a^{6}R\mu }{m_{s}m_{p}^{2}}}\times 10^{10}\ {\text{yr}}}$$

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 6\ {\frac {(149597871 km)^{6}(6378 km)(3×10^{10} N·m^{−2}) }{(1.988×10^{30} kg)(5.972×10^{24} kg)^{2}}}\times 10^{10}\ {\text{yr}}}$$

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 1.815\times10^{10} \ {\text{yr}}}$$

That comes out to a result of about 18 billion years. NASA gives [their estimate](https://science.nasa.gov/moon/tidal-locking/) as about 50 billion years, so considering how many assumptions we made to simplify the equation, being well within an order of magnitude is a pretty decent result. For context, Earth is about 4.5 billion years old right now.

Just for fun, and to better illustrate the tyranny of your semi-major axis on the time to tidal lock, here's the same calculation but assuming Earth orbits where Jupiter is now:

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 6\ {\frac {a^{6}R\mu }{m_{s}m_{p}^{2}}}\times 10^{10}\ {\text{yr}}}$$

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 6\ {\frac {(777908928 km)^{6}(6378 km)(3×10^{10} N·m^{−2}) }{(1.988×10^{30} kg)(5.972×10^{24} kg)^{2}}}\times 10^{10}\ {\text{yr}}}$$

$${\displaystyle t_{\text{lock}}\approx 3.588\times10^{19} \ {\text{yr}}}$$

As you can see, the time for that very same planet to tidally lock is now more than nine orders of magnitude longer - that is 36 quintillion years, or about 1.3 billion times longer than the universe itself has existed (assuming an age of 26.7 billion years as determined in 2023 by the [Royal Astronomical Society](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/524/3/3385/7221343?login=true)).

You can play around with the variables, and try using the original equation to remove some error from the assumptions if you know the actual values for your planetary system. While the semi-major axis is certainly dominant of the other variables, they will still have small effects.

### To answer the body: Yes.

TRAPPIST-1 is a star system with a star much smaller than our Sun (about 0.09 solar masses) and at least seven rocky planets. The fifth planet of that system, TRAPPIST-1f, orbits at only 0.03849 AU.

Proxima Centauri, the closest star to our own solar system, has a mass of only about 0.122 solar masses. One of its rocky planets, Proxima Centauri b, orbits at 0.04856 AU, or about 1.5 million kilometers further from its star than TRAPPIST-1f. Proxima Centauri b is almost certainly tidally locked to its host star.

Essentially, you seem to have an assumption that planetary systems must all be laid out as far apart as our own solar system. In reality, it is arguably quite common for several planetary bodies to form very close in to the host star, so being the fifth planet and being close enough for a quick tidal locking to take place are not mutually exclusive properties.